# importing a table from a webpage using pd.read_html

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use pd.read_html to import the table under "Daily Observations" from https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/us/mi/ann-arbor/date/2020-1

I tried this but the error of "HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" showed.

```
Jan = pd.read_html('https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/us/mi/ann-arbor/date/2020-1')
```

Alternatively, I copied the source code of the table and save it as an html file.

The html file looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTkF9.jpg

When I use pd.read_html to import this html file, it seems like the imported dataset is not a dataframe. The rows and columns gone messy like this:

```
[                                                  Time  \
0    Jan 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...   
1                                                  Jan   
2                                                    1   
3                                                    2   
4                                                    3   
..                                                 ...   
220                                               0.02   
221                                               0.00   
222                                               0.00   
223                                               0.00   
224                                               0.00   

                                    Temperature (Â° F)  \
0    Max Avg Min 38 30.8 26 47 41.8 35 45 42.8 39 3...   
1                                                  NaN   
2                                                  NaN   
3                                                  NaN   
4                                                  NaN   
..                                                 ...   
220                                                NaN   
221                                                NaN   
222                                                NaN   
223                                                NaN   
224                                                NaN
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: pd.read_html(/path/to/the/html/file)